# Angular Routes not working, can you spot the bug?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-controller

I am trying to route 2 partials to my index page, but so far only one route seem to work, the other is unresponsive. I have gone through the codes so many times, but can't seem to spot the issue. Would appreciate any insights.

Heres are my controllers:

```
    app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope','stream', function($scope, stream) {
    stream.then(function(data)  {
        $scope.photos = data;
    });  
}]);
```

This is the controller for the partial that fails to load

```
 app.controller('PhotoController', ['$scope','stream', '$routeParams', function($scope, stream, $routeParams) {
    stream.then(function(data)  {
        $scope.descript = data.items[$routeParams.photoid];
    });  
}]);
```

This is the

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="photo in photos.items"  >
     <div class="photo" >         
      <div>
       <img  class="col-md-2 thumbnail" ng-src="{{photo.media.m}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="height: 119px; width: 641px">
         <div class="row" id="title"><p1>{{photo.title}}</p1></div>
         <div class="row list-desc">
         <p1  id="author">{{photo.author}}</p1>
         <p1 id="pub-date">Published:{{photo.published | date}}</p1>
         <a id="view-link" href="description/{{$index}}">View on flickr</a>
          </div>
      </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the one that fails to load.

```
    <div class="container" ng-repeat="desc in descript" >
          <h1>{{desc.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

This is my routing:

```
    var app = angular.module('angularOne', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
       $routeProvider.
         when('/', {
          controller: 'HomeController',
          templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        }).
         when('/description/:photoid', {
          controller: 'PhotoController',
          templateUrl: 'views/photo.html'
        }).
         otherwise({
         redirectTo:'/' 
      });

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: Where is your route configuration?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @chase just appended the route config code.

Comment: @LeFex this is what I get: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Tough one. I don't really have an answer, but I guess you could double check all file names and paths, test if it works if you comment out the Controller associated with the view, check if the controller recieve the routeParams properly. Good luck with everything.

Comment: Thanks for your rresponse, I'll take another look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

desc should descript in the html, or the other way around in the js.

Comment: desc is simply looping through descript and displaying in the html partial.

Comment: I'm with LeFex then, it's likely simply a typo somewhere in the file paths.

Comment: I'll take another look at it then and I do hope i find something.